# How to make \n got to new line but start exactly underneath the start of current line?

Tags: php, html

I want the following output

`$text =  Hello, this is
         example text.`

instead of

`$text =  Hello, this is
example text.`

When I use **\n** it goes to start position in new line. How do I make it got exactly below current line with same start location?

Comment: Try `\t` this should work..

Answer (score 0):

In Coding if you want to Go for Next Line but Want text below your Text use this Tag:

```
<br> or <br/>
```

Here is Code For you In html :

```
<html>
<body>
    <p align="center">Hello World<br>
    Hey World</p>
</body>
</html>
```